# @ at start of WP7 tile title replaced by path: known issue?

Tags: windows-phone-7, tiles, pinning

I'm using the [ShellTile.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.PHONE.SHELL.SHELLTILE.CREATE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) method to create a secondary tile.  Users of the app I've developed have noticed that if the entity they are pinning has a name that starts with "@" (which is then used for the title of the tile), then the title that is displayed by the phone is "@\Applications\" ....

It looks to me as though the phone treats an "@" at the start of the name as special somehow, and replaces it with a path ...

Here I'm setting the [ShellTileData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltiledata%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).Title to "@Test".  This is what gets pinned:

[image: Screenshot showing pinned tile with weird name]

I've tried UrlEncoding the title - no luck.

Has anyone come across this before?  Is it a known issue?

Damian

I've accepted Colin's answer below.  This is the code I'm now using based on his suggestion:

```
...
if(initialData.Title.StartsWith("@")) {
    initialData.Title = '\uff20' + initialData.Title.Substring(1);
}
ShellTile.Create(uri, initialData);
```

Comment: Have you tried the other at-signs ... \uFF20 ＠ or \uFE6B ﹫ ?

Comment: \uff20 works!  Wonderful thing about unicode - so many choices :-)

Comment: cool! I have promoted this comment to an answer :-) Does it look fine on the tile? the character gets clipped in my browser.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Bizarre behavior by the shell API though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment ... give `\uFF20` a go, I doubt anyone will notice the difference between @ and ＠.

Comment: This works - I've added my updated code to the question, based on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Fleck from Microsoft responded here: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/100059/598687.aspx#598687

There is a mention of the issue under "Beware of the '@' Sign" on Peter Torr's blog here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2011/07/12/background-agents-part-3-of-3.aspx

Peter recommends adding a Zero-Width-Space unicode char (8203) to the start of tile names that begin with an @.

Answer (score 0):

Well while you guys talk "code," all I know is the "@" symbol as supplied by typing "shift+2" by your average EU, is extremely common. This is a GTD "Getting Things Done" practice that has been around for a number of years. So it may be more common than the average dev/coder may think.

In the meantime, thanks for looking into this Damian.